# Determine if set is finite or infinite, If finite, find its size

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$P(A)$ , where $A = P(\{a,b,c,d\})$

Please guide me on how to solve this.
Does $P$ refers to power set of $A$?? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time P is the power set of $A$.

If a finite set has a cardinality $n$, it’s power set has cardinality $2^{n}$. So the power set is finite in this case. One could write out the power set and show it is finite as well.

Comment: If any set has cardinality $n$, it's power set has cardinality $2^n$, works with infinities too.

Comment: I know. I stated the finite case because that’s what’s only relevant.